# Can't build docker compose on M1 chipset

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I tried to build the docker compose on M1 chipset and getting error as such:

```
/remi/enterprise/7/php73/aarch64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

But in my Intel chip, I haven't encountered this problem. Apparently there are not much solutions on the internet as well. Have anyone encountered the same problem? Here is the Dockerfile that causes the problem:

```
FROM centos:7

WORKDIR /home/project/source

RUN yum -y install epel-release yum-utils && \
    yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi- 
    release-7.rpm && \
    yum-config-manager --disable remi-php54 && \
    yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73 && \
    yum -y install \
    nginx \
    jq \
    php \
    php-fpm \
    php-cli \
    php-opcache \
    php-msgpack \
    php-redis \
    php-mbstring \
    php-intl \
    php-xml \
    php-gettext \
    php-imagick \
    php-pgsql \
    php-soap \
    php-pdo \
    php-mysqlnd \
    php-apcu \
    php-igbinary \
    php-json \
    php-memcache \
    php-xdebug \
    php-mysqlnd \
    php-openssl \
    php-opcache
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all

COPY config/php-fpm.d/www.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY config/php.d/90-project-php.ini /etc/php.d/90-project-php.ini

RUN mkdir /var/run/php-fpm && \
    chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php && \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/php-fpm/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/php-fpm/error.log

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]
```

It is constantly trying to find mirrors with no success.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /remi/enterprise/7/php73/aarch64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

Remi's Repository is only for x86_64 architecture for now.

You can try drpixel repository (rebuild of remi's packages)

See https://repo.drpixel.fr/

Comment: have the upgrading released?