# Run CentOS7 in docker container on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: php, docker, yum, arm64, apple-m1

I tried to run

```
yum -y install yum-utils
```

in the docker container on M1 Chip

and I got some errors like:

```
#8 11.59 https://mirror.netweaver.uk/remi/enterprise/7/safe/aarch64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
#8 11.59 Trying other mirror.
```

It works fine on Intel Chip.

I found an answer from [Can't build docker compose on M1 chipset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911250/cant-build-docker-compose-on-m1-chipset)

but it is an article which was written 4 months ago.

So I tried to search the `yum-utils` for `arm64` and I found [remi for aarch64](http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/remi/enterprise/7/remi/aarch64/)

but I have no idea to use this url.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Try to run first: yum update

Comment: Yeah, I have tried

Comment: try add `platform: linux/x86_64` on your docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.  after tried so hard to fix it, I decided to build a new image using ubuntu (temporary solution).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).